# How to use spark and mongo with play to calculate prediction?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am using play, scala and mongodb (salat).

I have following database structure-

```
[{
"id":mongoId,
"name":"abc",
"utilization":20,
"timestamp":1416668402352
},
{
"id":mongoId,
"name":"abc",
"utilization":30,
"timestamp":1415684102290
},
{
"id":mongoId,
"name":"abc",
"utilization":90,
"timestamp":1415684402210
},
{
"id":mongoId,
"name":"abc",
"utilization":40,
"timestamp":1415684702188
},
{
"id":mongoId,
"name":"abc",
"utilization":35,
"timestamp":1415684702780
}]
```

By using above data, I want to calculate utilization for current timestamp (By applying statistical algorithm).

To calculate it I am using spark. I have added following dependencies to build.sbt of play framework.

I have following questions.

1) How to calculate current utilization?? (using MLlib of spark)

2) Is it possible to query mongo collection to get some of fields using spark??

Answer (score 9):

There is a project named **Deep-Spark** that takes care about integrating spark with mongodb (and others datastores like cassandra, aerospike, etc).

https://github.com/Stratio/deep-spark

**You can check how to use it here:**

https://github.com/Stratio/deep-spark/blob/master/deep-examples/src/main/java/com/stratio/deep/examples/java/ReadingCellFromMongoDB.java

It is a very simple way to start working with mongodb and spark.

Sorry I can not help you with MLlib, but sure somebody will add something useful.

Disclaimer: I am currently working on Stratio.

Comment: Given link seems to be dead. Here is the correct link https://github.com/Stratio/deep-examples/blob/master/deep-mongodb/src/main/java/com/stratio/deep/examples/java/factory/ReadingCellFromMongoDB.java